# Create a custom success AWS API Gateway model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have not found anything on Stack Overflow and as many who have used AWS know, their documentation can be cumbersome. If all I need is a point to some documentation, I would appreciate the link.

I have built an API endpoint for a customer. Everything behind the Gateway works fine but I want to provide a different message for my customer for a success response other than a 200 status code with a body that reads : `null`.

I have got into the Models menu in API Gateway. I have tried to reverse engineer the error response but it appears to take an object, and i still get null on my 200s.

error Model Schema, default in API Gateway:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Error Schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "message" : { "type" : "string" }
  }
}
```

this URL in the JSON above points to a schema file which i have no idea how to use.

If the API key is INcorrect the gateway returns

```
{
   "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

how can i have API Gateway return the following  on success?:

```
{
   "message": "Success"
}
```

instead of

`null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my mistakes was that i was relying on API Gateway to give a response, even though i was using it as a gateway to a lambda function.

in lambda:

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

    event = JSON.stringify(event);

    await fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: event});

    context.succeed({message: "Success"});

};
```

i had to make my function async, and wait my fetch's response. once i got that i could use the callback and return the message. all works fine now. my response in postman is

```
{
    "message": "Success"
}
```

you could add conditionals to this also for other response types, or `.then().catch()` to handle success and fails. the solution is not asking API gateway to answer, but instead the endpoint you are using gateway for.

Hope this helps someone.